# R: Data Table cannot handle "?" as an na.strings() option

Tags: r, data.table, fread

I am trying to read in a very large data set using a data table in R (`library(data.table)`)

The data set codes missing values with a question mark `?`.  I am attempting to read in the data while simultaneously converting one column to a Date format.  I suspect my code will work, but `fread` is coverting all of the columns to character classes because it cannot handle the `?` as an `na.strings()` option.

I could resolve this through read.csv, but it's prohibitively slow to do so.  Does anybody know how to resolve this?

Here is my code:

```
setClass("date")
setAs("character","date", function(from) as.Date(from, format="%d/%m/%Y") )

DT<- fread("data.txt", na.strings="?", colClasses = c("date", "character", rep("numeric", 7)))
```

Comment: From `?fread`,  `na.strings` is `A character vector of strings to convert to NA_character_`. So it converts the column to `character` as you suspected. I guess that you have to coerce to numeric after reading the file.

Comment: But then there's no way to use the setAs function while reading it in, correct?

Comment: No, I don't think you can call an R function during the call to `fread`. You just need to coerce afterwards (I guess that in most cases it should not be a big deal).

Comment: Use a system editing program like sed or awk to do a global replacement.